# Why does my header interfere with my hyperlink?

Tags: android, html, css, cordova

For some reason my `#menu` `<a>` is being moved to a different location every time I try to add my `#menubarheader` `<h1>`. I am fairly knowledgeable when it comes to html and css, but I just cannot find a solution to this problem. Here is my code, Please help.

**HTML :**

```
<div id="right">
    <div id="menubar">
        <h1 id="menubarheader">Latest News</h1>
        <a href="#menu" id="button">&#8801;</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
#menubar {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: maroon;
    height: 80px;
    line-height: 80px;
}
#button {
    color: black;
    font-size: 4em;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: lighter;
    padding: 0px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: left;
}
#menubarheader {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: 32px;
}
```

I am wondering if the line height is the problem? But I want to keep the line height the way it is because I need these `#menubar` children to be vertically aligned. I am making an Android app using PhoneGap, so if anyone can help, it would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the id - `menubar` to relative and the id's `button` and `menubarheader` to absolute.  I believe that is what you were looking for.  Here is the JSFiddle:  [>>>CLICK HERE<<<](http://jsfiddle.net/9E9Ss/1/)

HTML:

```
<div id="right">
    <div id="menubar">
        <h1 id="menubarheader">Latest News</h1>
        <a href="#menu" id="button">&#8801;</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#menubar, #menubarheader {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
}
#menubar {
    min-width: 250px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: maroon;
}
#button, #menubarheader {
    position: absolute;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-weight: lighter;
}
#button {
    padding: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 4em;
    color: black;
}
#menubarheader {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 32px;
}
```

Comment: Ah thank you very much! That did the trick! Now I can finally work on my app!